# Text sticks out of block quote

Tags: bug, design

Reading [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/57315/20264), I noticed some text sticking out of the edge of the blockquote

[image]

Comment: To add some details, this is a numbering list inside quote block with starting number 21717.

Comment: What browser, including version?

Comment: @freiheit - Google Chrome: Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @richard Looks right in Chrome under linux,   Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Criggie - Are you looking at the [unrevised version](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/revisions/57315/10)?

Comment: Yes, I was.  Revision 11 in the edit history shows it all hanging out to the left.